# Keras (Theano backend + GPU + CUDA) not working with PyDev

Tags: gpu, pydev, theano, keras

I am using Keras (Theano backend) with GPU and Cuda 8.0. Everything works fine when I run my code in Jupyter or Ubuntu terminal. However, inside Eclipse (PyDev) I receive the following error importing Keras:

> ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: libcublas.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)

I have double checked the interpreter and it is the same python as the terminal and Jupyter. I have also added the /usr/local/cuda/lib64/ to the pythonpath of the interpreter but still the same error !

Anybody knows how to fix the issue with PyDev?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but not the reason.
I started Eclipse from Ubuntu terminal and it worked fine. I don't know why it couldn't find CUDA path when I start it by double clicking on its icon.